# Internet speed lower for websites which are physically very far during day time

Tags: networking, internet, isp

I got a new internet connection recently and I am testing my internet speed and I am noticing some strange observations. For the record, my location is India and typical speed test websites report 3ms ping time.

Day time:

- Server in India: 50Mbps
- Server in Singapore: 20Mbps
- Server in Europe/US: 2Mbps

Nighttime:

- Server in India/Singapore/Europe/US: 50Mbps

I am curious:

A) Why during the day time in my country, access to servers in foreign countries is slower than night time?

B) Who is to blame for "A". My ISP or someone else?

C) Why Singapore, a region physically closer offers better than speed than Europe?

Note: I ran speed test mainly using a download manager (both in a single section and multiple section mode)

Comment: Do all the servers report the same (or close to the same) ping time, no matter the time of day? If distant servers report much longer pings at the same time the connection is slower, that's most likely due to congestion somewhere along the line.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe Yes exactly. The farther, the server. The higher the ping time. But how ping Time affects downloading speed when using downloading manager

Comment: Lower ping time tends to mean a better, more direct connection. Less things that could potentially slow it down. Also my question was, does the ping time change drastically from day to night?

Comment: @BenjiWiebe Not really. This is why it's really surprising.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe - you are not correct On reasonable capacity links lower ping times are more closely correlated with lower physical distance and fewer routers. Jitter (difference ping times and packet loss are better indicators ofnl congestion).  Im I'm NZ. If you could provide 10ms ping times to Australia you could become rich beyond your wildest dreams - but to do so the signal would need to go faster then the speed of light...

Comment: @VarunAgw higher pings can reduce download speeds on single threaded TCP connections.

Comment: @davidgo Why exactly?

Comment: @davidgo I understand the speed of light limitation, I was (incorrectly) thinking that the ping time, download speed, and time of day were all correlated. Also bufferbloat can definitely cause drastically increased latency as the link is saturated.

Comment: @VarunAgw That bit is at the very edge of my knowledge. I believe that TCP uses latency as a factor in calculating the maximum transmission speed as part of congestion control. Remember to that received packets need to be acknowledged, so the longer this acknowledgement takes the slower the throughput, depending on buffer size.

Comment: @davidgo I am not sure but I think you can send multiple packets without waiting for first packet. Even if it's wrong, it makes you wonder why I get high speed at night time even with the same ping time.

Comment: @VarunAgw your stack likely indeed buffers packets, but there is a limit, and its still used in congestion control.  You will that during peak your TCP connection drops (a very small) number of packets. These lost packets are used as a signal to the sender to reduce the transmission speed. That's the way TCP works. The higher the latency the longer ramping speed back up takes. This is used to control congestion.